# XML manipulation with F# TypeProvider

Tags: f#, type-providers, fsharp.data.typeproviders

Given the following XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Persons>
  <Person>
    <Name>Person 1</Name>
    <Age>30</Age>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name>Person 2</Name>
    <Age>32</Age>
  </Person>
</Persons>
```

I want to add a Person to the collection and I was hoping that could be accomplished with the Xml TypeProvider API.

My approach is the following:

```
type PersonXmlProvider = XmlProvider<""".\Persons.xml""">

let personsXml = PersonXmlProvider.GetSample()
personsXml.XElement.Add(new PersonXmlProvider.Person("Person 3", 33))
personsXml.XElement.Save("Persons.xml")
```

**What happens:**
The person is added to the xml collection and written to the file.

**Unexpected:**
But the encoding is not correct since the XML-Tags are encoded as `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively instead of < and >.

What am I missing?

The documentation says that UTF-8 is the default.

#### Update

Resulting XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Persons>
  <Person>
    <Name>Person 1</Name>
    <Age>30</Age>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name>Person 2</Name>
    <Age>32</Age>
  </Person>&lt;Person&gt;
  &lt;Name&gt;Person 3&lt;/Name&gt;
  &lt;Age&gt;33&lt;/Age&gt;
&lt;/Person&gt;
</Persons>
```

Comment: Show the resulting XML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method `XElement.Add(content: obj)` takes in a content object.

`PersonXmlProvider.Person.ToString` serializes the type to XML and this gets added as a text node to your main document.

Thus when it is serialized, the text node is escaped, and you see XML entities in the output.

P.S.

The solution is to use `XElement` all the way.

```
let person = new PersonXmlProvider.Person("Person 3", 33)
personsXml.XElement.Add(person.XElement)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. #relieved

Comment: You're welcome, @MarcusK. (: 
You might also want to update to the newest build because of https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/issues/975